# nginx extract a value from post and get

Tags: nginx, post

I need to make a reverse proxy using nginx that proxy clients according to a specific id that they provides inside they post/get:

```
clientid=<value from the clientid inside the post/get>

if clientid=XXX {
  ProxyPass server1
}
if clientid=YYY {
  ProxyPass server2
}
```

How can I achieve that with nginx ?

with @workaround comments, i get something like this:

```
location ~ ^/(api|newapi)/(v2/)?(xxxx|yyyy|zzzz) {
    echo_read_request_body;
    echo $request_body;
    if ($request_body ~* (.*)?clientid=2621(.*)?) {
      proxy_pass https://apiold;
    }
    proxy_pass https://apinew;
    include proxy.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [official nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) try using:

```
  if (($request_body ~* (.*)clientID#1(.*)) )

 {

    proxy_pass server1;

  }

if (($request_body ~* (.*)clientID#2(.*)) )  {

    proxy_pass server2;

  }

}
```

Comment: It seems that I miss something : `nginx: [emerg] invalid condition "($request_body"`. I am using the free `nginx-1.14.2-1.el7_4.ngx.x86_64`. Do I need a specific module ?

Comment: Did you check the brackets? Maybe there's a bracket extra or missing in the syntax.

Comment: there is  1 too much bracket that I fixed, bu it seems that request_body is always empty

Comment: For testing reasons you may use `echo $request_body;` inside the if brackets,above the redirect and check if it is indeed empty.

Comment: `location ~ ^/(api|newapi)/(v2/)?(xxxx|yyyy|zzzz) {
    echo_read_request_body;
    echo $request_body;
    if ($request_body ~* (.*)?clientid=2621(.*)?) {
      proxy_pass https://apiold;
    }
    proxy_pass https://apinew;
    include proxy.conf;
  }`

Comment: I added a block in the original with the config I have according to your advices. I get nothing out of the echo and if is not working, any idea ?